# How to run a T-SQL query daily on an Azure database

Tags: sql, azure, scheduling

I am trying to migrate a database from a sql server into Azure. This database have 2 rather simple TSQL script that inserts data. Since the SQL Agent does not exist on Azure, I am trying to find an alternative.

I see the Automation thing, but it seems really complex for something as simple as running SQL scripts. Is there any better or at least easier way to do this ?

I was under the impression that there was a scheduller for that for I can't find it.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are several ways to  run a scheduled Task/job on the azure sql database for your use case -

1. If you are comfortable using the existing on-premise sql sever agent you can connect to your azure sql db(using linked servers) and execute jobs the same way we used to on on-premise sql server.
2. Use Automation Account/Runbooks to create sql jobs. If you see marketplace you can find several examples on azure sql db(backup,restore,indexing jobs..). I guess you already tried it and does not seem a feasible solution to you.
3. Another not very famous way could be to use the webjobs(under app service web app) to schedule tasks(can use powershell scripts here). The disadvantage of this is you cannot change anything once you create a webjob
4. As @jayendran suggested Azure functions is definitely an option to achieve this use case.
5. If some how out of these if you do not have options to work with the sql directly , there is also "Scheduler Job Collection"  available in azure to schedule invocation of HTTP endpoints, and the sql operation could be abstracted/implemented in that endpoint. This would be only useful for less heavy sql operations else if the operation takes longer chances are it might time out.

Comment: It's not that automation is not a feasable solution. It just seems really complicated but something so simple in the past. The SQL Agent was simple enough and I don't know Powershell. I just felt like there should be an easy "SQL Script scheduler" option.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [Azure Functions to Run the T-SQL Queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-scenario-database-table-cleanup) for Schedule use [Timely Trigger](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-functions/functions-create-scheduled-function).

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can use Microsoft Flow (https://flow.microsoft.com) in order to create a programmed flow with an SQL Server connector. Then in the connector you set the SQL Azure server, database name, username and password.

[SQL Server connector](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZACgS.png)

There are many options but the ones that you can use to run a T-SQL query daily are these:

[SQL Connector options](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LffeX.png)

- Execute a SQL Query
- Execute stored procedure

You can also edit your connection info in Data --> Connections menu.